# error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

```
In file included from /Boost/Implementation/boost_1_59_0/include/boost/geometry/core/radian_access.hpp:33:0,
                 from /Boost/Implementation/boost_1_59_0/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:43,
                 from /../../abc.h:11,
                 from /../../xyz.cpp:9:
/Boost/Implementation/boost_1_59_0/include/boost/geometry/util/math.hpp: In static member function 'static bool boost::geometry::math::detail::equals<Type, true>::apply(const Type&, const Type&, const Policy&)':
/Boost/Implementation/boost_1_59_0/include/boost/geometry/util/math.hpp:166:26: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
/Boost/Implementation/boost_1_59_0/include/boost/geometry/util/math.hpp:166:54: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
```

The error is in the infine call from below code of math.hpp file.

```
 if (boost::math::isfinite(a) && boost::math::isfinite(b))
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: One guess is that you include some header before the Boost header, perhaps a C header, that defines `isfinite` as a macro.

Comment: @BoPersson How I can check the which file is having isfinite macro?
Here we are using the boost::math:: name space explicitly so I expect it should take from boost only.

Comment: @swapnil - Macros don't respect namespaces, so if there is a `#define infinite(x) something`, the compiler will see `boost::math::something` instead of the original code.